# How to add a new rt_field In Sphinx RT on a pre-existing index?

Tags: sphinx

Using sphinx RT (realtime), I have a current working setup.

But I want to add a new field to track: `rt_field new_field`

After adding the above to my sphinx.conf, and issuing a `/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch restart`, trying to populate sphinx produces an error saying that my `new_field` is an unknown column.
*(The documentation doesn't clearly mentions this for RT indexes.)*

The question:

Do I have to delete the index file and let sphinx recreate it or is there a way to update one and how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any changes in Sphinx RT index structure required to recreate index and re-index from scratch.
So, you need to create new index and re-index all data.

Comment: In details: you run `service sphinxsearch stop`, erase all your `rt.*` files, and run `service sphinxsearch start`. Then you can index the data again. Note that you may need to remove the binlog too (under Debian, it's in `/var/lib/sphinxsearch/`).